# Export Specific Cells From Excel To MS Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, export

The code below (given to me) works but I don’t understand  the Values (line line 9). I keep getting error messages when I try to add more cells. Im new to VBA could someone add more fields so I can better understand, such as:

C5 into Ingredient2
C6 into Ingredient3
C7 into Ingredient4
L5 into Lot2
L6 into Lot3
L7 into Lot4 
and a whole bunch more.

The values below are arbitrary just for testing. Please tack a look at my spreadsheet
The spreadsheet I am using is here: https://mega.co.nz/#!2cZ3kKAZ!BL-HJM...1tZewrw-CH-1Dc

```
Sub Button10_Click()
  Dim strSQL As String

  Set appAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")

  appAccess.Visible = False

  strSQL = "INSERT INTO [Finished Batches] ([Production Date],[Lot_Number],[Ingredient1],[Amount1]) " & _
           "VALUES (#" & Range("C5") & "#,'" & Range("D5") & "','" & Range("F23") & _
           "'," & Range("G23") & ")"

  With appAccess
    .OpenCurrentDatabase ("C:\users\jay neuh\desktop\database\ss database.mdb")
    .DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL, dbFailOnError
    .CloseCurrentDatabase
  End With

  Set appAccess = Nothing
End Sub
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: What is the full error message you receive when you run that code?

Answer (score 0):

Access is using a SQL language to handle data, in this case an INSERT command.

An INSERT commands looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO [my_table_name] ([my_string_column],[my_number_column],[my_date_column])
VALUES ('my text value', 42, #2015-01-31#)
```

Notice a few things:

- the number of columns must be the same as number of values
- if you are passing text, it needes to be wrapped in single quotes
- if you are passing a date, it needs to be wrapped in hash signs
- if you are passing a number, it must not be wrapped

You didn't mention what kind of error you were getting, but if in your Access database the field [Lot_Number] is actually of a numeric type, wrapping it in single quotas like in your example could be the problem.

You should check [Introduction to Access SQL](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Introduction-to-Access-SQL-d5f21d10-cd73-4507-925e-bb26e377fe7e)

EDIT: You should always use

```
Debug.Print strSQL
```

to preview your SQL statement, you'll be more likely to spot if you have a syntax error somewhere in the code, like a missing comma, single quote or a bracket.